# Automatically switch scalebar units at certain scale

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar

I have a scalebar with a element-width of 70 mm. It has three segments and their width is set to be between 50 and 60 mm. Scalebar units are set to [m]. This works fine when it comes to automated adaption to different scales.

But when my scales get smaller (1:30,000, 1:50,000 and similar) the labels of the scalebar change from hundreds of meters to thousands, which reduces readability.

Is there a way to automatically change the scalebar units e.g. from [m] to [km] when crossing a certain threshold of scale?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't find a manual solution. But It is easily performed using PyQGIS.

```py
threshold = 50000 # 1:50.000

# get layout and items
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName("layout_name")
mapItem = layout.itemById("map_name")
scalebar = layout.itemById("scalebar_name")

def map_extent_changed():    
    if mapItem.scale()>= threshold:        
        scalebar.setUnits(1) # 1: kilometer
        scalebar.setUnitLabel("km")
    else:
        scalebar.setUnits(0) # 0: meter
        scalebar.setUnitLabel("m")
    
mapItem.extentChanged.connect(map_extent_changed)

# to be sure 
# if isinstance(mapItem, QgsLayoutItemMap):
#    mapItem.extentChanged.connect(map_extent_changed)
```

[image]