# Setting layout scale bar to change automatically from kilometers to meters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layouts, scale-bar

Recently I’ve been creating a layout for my colleagues. Because they are likely to produce maps of various scales, I wanted to implement in the layout a scale bar that could automatically change from kilometers to meters depending on the canvas zoom.

The kind of errors, which I want to avoid is like the one below :

[image]

The scale bar is set to kilometers, but because the zoom is at a neighbourhood/plot scale, you can’t simply read the values. A scale bar set to meters would be much more appropriate :

[image]

Once again, I would like to see these changes in the scale bar settings being operated automatically by the software.

Do you think that expressions like : `layer_property( 'layername', 'extent') bounds_width(geom), bounds_height(geom), map_extent_width, map_extent_height` could be helpful ?

I noticed that the canevas scale bar was able of such performances (View --> Decorations --> Scale bar).
Here is the result when I zoom at a neighbourhood scale (left corner):

[image]

And the result when I zoom at a city scale :

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.10.8, the projection is always Lambert 93.

---

Now that I've been pinpointed the reason of the *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*, I'm carrying on with the well-indented script.

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager() #Returns the project’s layout manager, which manages compositions within the project.
layout = manager.layoutByName("carte_siare_type_A4_paysage")
mapItem = layout.itemById("Map 1")
scalebar = layout.itemById("Scalebar")

def map_extent_changed():    
    if mapItem.scale()>= threshold:        
        scalebar.setUnits(1) # 1: kilometer
        scalebar.setUnitLabel("km")
    else:
        scalebar.setUnits(0) # 0: meter
        scalebar.setUnitLabel("m")
        
    mapItem.extentChanged.connect(map_extent_changed)
```

The result returned when I exectue the command is the following:

```
exec(open('C:/Users/tec21/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp7l0qm5b8.py'.encode('utf-8')).read()
```

It seems like the code is working. I have no warning messages in the console. However, when I open the layout and see if there are changes operating in the scale bar when I zoom to bigger and smaller scales that 1/50 000, nothing happens, the measure remains in kilometers, which is the default setting, whatever the zoom is.

Comment: It's reasonably easy with PyQGIS, but it means running a script in your project. I'm not sure how portable/user-friendly that is if you are making a template for others to use.

Comment: You can use the script in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387956/29431).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. So far I've never been coding very much with PyQgis, nor python. But let's give it a try. Once I'll have achieved this goal, I will decide whether use it or not for my colleagues. Kadir, do you mind helping again ? I copied/pasted your code, which I had modified to suit the proper names of my layouts, maps,... but I'm stuck with scalebar.setUnits(1). In the main post is the whole code :

Comment: Indentation is important in python.  As in the linked answer and as the error message is saying, you need to indent `scalebar.setUnits(1)` to the right of the preceding `if` statement

Comment: Possible workarounds that are much less elegant than PyQGIS would be to 1: insert two scale bars in your layout, one in meters and one in km, and then have the user drag the one they want into the actual layout and the other out of it, or 2: create one layout for scales that kilometers work best and one for where meters work best.

Comment: Thank you Johns, but I'll try to be a bit determined here and not use kind of tricks which aren't resolving the problem. JGH, thank you for your comment. I took a look at forums, conversations on the indentation topic. It was interesting.

Comment: Try un-indenting `mapItem.extentChanged.connect(map_extent_changed)`, so it is aligned on the left, like in the original script. It is currently inside the function and therefore the signal emitted by `.extentChanged` is not calling the function.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I brought the correction to the code. This indentation in python is a bit more tricky that I expected !

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `threshold`, and `mapItem.extentChanged` shouldn't be in method definition block.
Use like this:

```py
threshold = 50000 # 1:50.000
    
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager() 
layout = manager.layoutByName("carte_siare_type_A4_paysage")
mapItem = layout.itemById("Map 1")
scalebar = layout.itemById("Scalebar")

def map_extent_changed():    
    if mapItem.scale()>= threshold:        
        scalebar.setUnits(1) # 1: kilometer
        scalebar.setUnitLabel("km")
    else:
        scalebar.setUnits(0) # 0: meter
        scalebar.setUnitLabel("m")

mapItem.extentChanged.connect(map_extent_changed)
```

Comment: I haven't tested in Windows yet.

Comment: Thank you Kadir, I miscopied/mispasted the code in my previous edit. I can assure you that Threshold was already part of my code. However like Matt and you stressed it, mapItem.extentChanged was not properly indented. I brought that correction too. Now, I'm facing an other error: AttributeError: 'NonType' object has no attribute 'extentChanged'

Comment: Is there a map item named "Map 1" in the layout?

Comment: I believe I should give a "definition" to extentChanged, like you did for mapItem, scalebar,.. so far I can't think of something else required. I mean we have the project, the layout manager, the different layout manager items. By the way, I should emphasise that I'm working with Windows11.

Comment: Yes, it is the map itself.